# Unable to get the value from json object in javascript

Tags: javascript, json

unable to get the **value_1**  from dataObject.Showing undefined.

```
        var errorMessage;
        var dataObject ={"project_type":"{\"value_1\":\"Ground Mount\"}"};
        var project_type_str = dataObject['project_type'];
        project_type_str = JSON.stringify(project_type_str);
        if (project_type_str != null && project_type_str.length != 0) {
            errorMessage = '';
        } else {
            errorMessage = 'Please select a project type';
        }
        alert(project_type_str);
        var responseJson = {};
        var project_type_obj = JSON.parse(project_type_str);
        alert(project_type_obj);
        var value = project_type_obj["value_1"];

        alert(value);
```

Thanks for your answers.Please help me

Comment: Its not clear what you are trying to do

Comment: Why this step: `project_type_str = JSON.stringify(project_type_str);` ? `project_type_str` is already JSON

Comment: project_type_str = JSON.stringify(project_type_str); makes no sense

Comment: What have you tried already? e.g. using `JSON.parse` instead of `JSON.stringify`?

Comment: thanks all for your comments.It worked after removing  project_type_str = JSON.stringify(project_type_str);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`project_type_str` is already a string, so no need to JSON.stringify it.
The code should work fine if you remove the line

Remove this line

```
project_type_str = JSON.stringify(project_type_str);
```

A comparison for your better understandability

**With original code**

[image]

**With the line removed**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You don't need those extra quotes and escape characters to define the object. Do this:

```
var dataObject = {
   "projectType": {
      "value1": "groundMount"
   }
};
```

EDIT: I now see that you were intentionally writing JSON in its string representation so that you can parse it later. I hope that you have a special use case where you'd need to do something like that; otherwise, defining the object like I have will be much easier to deal with.